# Create PR from previous commits

Tags: git, github

I have a local history of commits

```
A-B-C-D (tip)
```

Now I'd like to create pull requests on github for each of the commits B, C, and D. For commit B this is what I am doing:

```
git checkout B~1
git checkout -b pr-B
git cherry-pick B
git push
```

This seems to work and create a PR with commit B. Now imagine that some changes are requested and I add them as commit B':

```
A-B-C-D
  \-B'
```

I push these changes and now its time to merge the PR. I am a bit confused about what will happen once I pull the merged branch from remote. I suppose that remote will have:

```
A-B-B'
```

But I would like that my local history will be:

```
A-B-B'-C-D
```

Can this be achieved? How?

Comment: Then you need to rebase `C-D` from `B` onto `B'`.

Comment: I guess what is confusing me is that the merge of B' to B happens at github. So I can't simply do `git pull` of the main branch, right?

Comment: If you add the `--rebase` option it will rebase your local branch onto the updated remote branch instead of merging it.

Comment: I see. Does the commit from where I do ```git pull --rebase``` matter? Do I need to do it from the tip of my local history?

Comment: Yes, the branch that is currently checked out will be rebased (as far as I know).

Comment: It worked as expected. Thank you!